# Are there switches with a direct connection between two ports when the power is off?

Tags: networking, switch, power

Are there switches which have a direct connection between two ports (e.g. port 1 and 2) when the power is not plugged in? I would like those two ports linked as if there was a direct connection with a cable instead of a (switched off) switch in between. As soon as the power is plugged in, the switch should operate as usual.

Are there any? Is it probably a common behavior of some models? Is there a name for that feature?

Comment: Don't think so. Certainly uncommon. Not to my knowledge.